# Clang Source to Source Transformation

Tags: clang, llvm-clang, libtooling

I am working on some Clang source-to-source transformation. I am doing it from Clang source code: `clang/tools/extra`. What I do is that I am adding a `printf("Hello World\n");` at the beginning of the main method. It works perfectly, I run my tool as `bin/add-code ../../test/hello.c` and it turns:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("This is from main ....\n");

  return 0;
}
```

to this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
  printf("Hello World\n");
  printf("This is from main ....\n");

  return 0;
}
```

*add-code* is my clang libtool that I have written.
But this rewritter only write changes to the terminal; while I want to compile hello.c with the modification and want to do it with clang command, `clang -c hello.c` not like I have done here.
How could I do that?

Comment: Register the clang plugin to make it automatically or just `alias clang=add-code ... | clang`? I'm not good at shell script, just a idea.

Comment: Do you know how to register clang plugin so that it will automatically be called while Clang tries to compile?

Comment: Here is a simple tutorial. http://railsware.com/blog/2014/02/28/creation-and-using-clang-plugin-with-xcode/